# How can I create Apple Dictionary File?

Tags: macos, dictionary

There is generally a dictionary.app on the Mac-OS.
But there isn't any dictionary development kit on the X-Code.
Now i use the X-Code (Mavericks and Yosemite).
So I downloaded the the auxiliary tools package from developer.apple.com/downloads and applied it to the /Applications/Utilites/.
And run the command "make" and "make install".
But when I reopen Dictionary.app, it couldn't do any action about of my Dictionary file.
What's the problem?

I want to make my own dictionary now.

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully made a dictionary you should put the file in `/Library/Dictionaries`.

In Sierra you have to make that folder yourself, as Apple has moved its own dictionaries to another location and no longer has this one.  It should still work, however.

You can find useful information in [Apple's Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/prepare/prepare.html)